# Obtener total de registros importados con laravel excel

Tags: php, laravel-8

Realizo la importación de registros mediante la librería Laravel/Excel. Todo funciona de forma correcta pero me gustaría obtener el número total de registros importados cuando se lleva a cabo dicha acción.

¿Cómo puedo obtener este dato?

Actualmente tengo el siguiente código:

Clase de importación donde defino variable $numrows que incremento por cada iteración en el proceso de importación y creo método getter para obtener desde el controlador los datos almacenados en la misma.

```
private $numrows = 0;

public function collection(Collection $rows)
{
    $cod_cliente = auth()->user()->client->id;

    foreach ($rows as $row) 
    {

        $this->$numrows++;

        /*Asignación de Cód Employee */
        $cod_employee = 'CNT-' . $cod_cliente . '-' . $row['cod_employee'];
       
        $sex = ucfirst($row['sex']);

        Employee::create(
            [
                'cod_employee'      => $cod_employee,
                'sex'               => $sex,
                'age'               => $row['age'],
                'birth_date'        => $row['birth_date'],
                'educational_level' => $row['educational_level'],
                'num_children'      => $row['num_children'],
                'client_id'         => $cod_cliente
            ]
        );
    }
}

public function getRowCount(): int
{
    return $this->numrows;
}
```

Controlador que valida la existencia de un archivo para importar y obtiene el número de registros importados. Pero aquí me dice que la variable $numrows no está definida.

```
public function importEmployees(Request $request)
{
    $validatedData = $request->validate(
        [
            'file' => 'required',
        ]
    );
    
    try {
        $import = new EmployeesImport();
        Excel::import($import, request()->file('file'));

        $totalreg = $import->getRowCount();

        Log::info(
            "¡¡Importación de registros!!. La importación de empleados se ha completado." 
        );

        return redirect()->back()->with(
            'success', 'Datos importados correctamente.'
        );
    } catch (\Throwable $th) {
        Log::error(
            "¡¡ERROR!!. Proceso de importación no completado. Error: "
            . $th->getMessage()
        );

        return redirect()->route('admin.employees.index')->with(
            'error', 'Error de importación. Contacte con el administador del sistema. '
            . $th->getMessage()
        );
    }   
}
```

Un saludo.

Comment: [Edita](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/515756/edit) la pregunta y pon el código de como realizas la importación de esos registros para que podamos ayudarte mejor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Según parece no hay ninguna función preestablecida que pueda usarse para conseguir ese dato.

Aún así, en la propia documentación de laravel-excel explican cómo realizarlo mediante la creación del método `getRowCount()`.

Los pasos para ello se encuentran en este enlace: https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/architecture/objects.html#getters

Y una vez realizados podremos ejecutar dicho método:

```php
Excel::import($import, request()->file('file'));
dd('Número de filas importadas: ' . $import->getRowCount());
```

**Actualización**

Despues de implementar esta solución y modificar la pregunta inicial, habia un nuevo error tipográfico que aparece en la pregunta final, donde se debe cambiar esto:

```
$this->$numrows++;
```

por esto:

```
$this->numrows++;
```

Comment: Hola, me lanza el siguiente error: App\Imports\EmployeesImport::getRowCount()

Comment: Lo estaba mirando ahora justamente... no es una funcion existente como pensaba, sino que hay que crearla tal como explica aqui:  https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/architecture/objects.html#getters

Comment: Cierto, pero a pesar de ello me dice que la variable no está definida. Undefined variable: numrows. numrows es donde almaceno el total de registros importados.

Comment: mmm... no se si has seguido correctamente los pasos indicados en esa página.  Alli actuan sobre la variable $import ... esta otra que dices no se cual es ni tampoco la veo en el codigo de tu pregunta, por lo tanto poco puedo decirte sobre ello, lo siento.

Comment: No será este el problema?  `$this->$numrows++;`??  no deberia ser `$this->numrows++;`???

Comment: Perdona, tienes razón. He actulizado mi pregunta con el códido añadido en el que declaro variable para recoger número de registros importados que incremento en cada iteración y defino método getter para obtener la misma desde el controlador. Pero me lanza el error de que la variable $numrows no está definida.

Comment: Cierto. Lo tenía ante mis ojos y no lo veía. Gracias por todo. Un saludo.

Comment: Me alegro que ya te vaya bien.  Si crees que mi respuesta te ha servido y merece ser aceptada hazlo, asi no quedara pendiente para siempre (aunque en este caso no he puesto apenas código porque me parecia que estaba ya todo en esa web... como prefieras, es para que no vengan con más soluciones y pierdan el tiempo si ya lo tienes claro tambien).

Comment: Aceptada. Gracias de nuevo.